# Erro 405 ao utilizar o HttpPost no Android

Tags: android, json

Ao fazer um *post* para o servidor através da *HttpPost* do Android recebo um erro 405. Outras aplicações fazem o mesmo *post* com sucesso, apenas quando parte do Android que recebo esse erro. Alguém sabe o motivo?

Meu código no Android é:

```
private class sendSignUpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.text_check_data));
    dialog.show();
    checkConnection();
    //checkFields();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.text_creating_account));
    dialog.setProgress(75);

    JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObjSend.put("action", "signup");
        jsonObjSend.put("firstname", FIRSTNAME);
        jsonObjSend.put("lastname", LASTNAME);
        jsonObjSend.put("email", EMAIL);
        jsonObjSend.put("password", PASSWORD);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nerd.com.br/");
    httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "br.com.nerd");
    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    StringEntity se = null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    httppost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("=============>" + httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.text_check_network, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String strResponse = null;
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
            System.out.println("=============>" + response);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return strResponse;
}
```

Comment: Estranho... Esse código não parece ter nenhum problema. Tem a possibilidade de trocar o `responseHandler.handleResponse(response);` por `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`. Fiz um teste com essa troca e eu ganho um 404 `Cannot POST /` (É claro que coloquei dados falsos no JSON). Coloquei meu código nesse `Gist`: https://gist.github.com/wakim/3c5bc2045f248e48a64e. Rodei a mesma requisição usando o http://www.hurl.it/ e foi o mesmo 404.

Comment: Olá @Wakim alterei mas não mudou nada.

Comment: Ainda com 405? Fazendo o teste pelo site também (no desktop) ou só no mobile?

Comment: Ainda com 405, muito estranho, só pelo Android, testando no Desktop funciona perfeitamente. Fiz um post pelo plugin Advanced Rest Client do Chrome e funciona. Posts de outros sites também funcionam.

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser... Espero que outra pessoa consiga te ajudar. Uma última tentativa seria usar outro `Stack` para fazer esse request... Se não se incomodar de usar ou o `OkHttp` ou o `Volley` ou outra biblioteca que faça requisições... Só para verificar se corrige o problema. Fiz outro código usando o `AndroidHttpClient` que é um `wrapper` do `HttpClient`, não sei se vai mudar muita coisa: https://gist.github.com/wakim/3c5bc2045f248e48a64e.

Comment: Com o AndroidHttpClient continua com o mesmo problema, vou seguir seus conselhos e tentar com o OkHttp e o Volley. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Tudo certo, descobri que o problema estava relacionado com o domínio que não havia sido propagado. @Wakim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar a resposta aqui para que outros possam ver que a pergunta foi respondida:

" o problema estava relacionado com o domínio que **não havia sido propagado**. "